# how can I write a matrix in a text file?

Tags: matlab

I have array `a=[1 2 3 4 5 6]`, and also array `b=[9 8 7 6 5 4];`
there is 2*6 matrix `p=[a; b]`, I mean `p=[1 2 3 4 5 6; 9 8 7 6 5 4];`
I want to write matrix p in a file but 6*2, I mean the outcome is

```
[1 9; 2 8;3 7; 4 6;5 5; 3 4]
```

is this a correct matlab code for this??

```
ff = fopen('final.txt','wt');
fprintf(final, '%f\n', p)
fclose(final)
```

Comment: I think the second last number in the 'outcome' based on vector `a` and `b` should be a `6`. Like this: `[1 9; 2 8;3 7; 4 6;5 5; 6 4]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it. The functions `fprintf` and `fclose` need the handle `ff` as the first argument. Then you have to add a second column to the definition of the output-format like this `%f\t%f\n`. The `\t` generates a tab and `\n` generates a line break.

Change it to this code and it will work as expected:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
b = [9 8 7 6 5 4];
p = [a; b];

ff = fopen('filename.txt','wt');
fprintf(ff,'%f\t%f\n', p);
fclose(ff);
```

The file looks like this:

```
1.000000    9.000000
2.000000    8.000000
3.000000    7.000000
4.000000    6.000000
5.000000    5.000000
6.000000    4.000000
```

---

If you want a solution that work with a variable number of rows (in `p`) respectively columns (in the file) then you can change the line to the following one:

```
fprintf(ff,[repmat('%f\t',1,size(p,1)-1),'%f\n'], p);
```

This dynamically generates the correct amount of `%f\t` needed

---

If you don't want floating point numbers, change `%f` to `%d`. Or find the format of your choosing [here](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html#inputarg_formatSpec). Instead of `\t` you can simply use spaces but then the output isn't aligned when numbers with different length are stored.

Comment: thank u. If I want the first column to be floating and the second column to be exponentioal, should I write fprintf(ff, '%f %e\n',p)??

Comment: @david323 Replace the second `%f` with `%e` or `%E`. *Edit: As you wrote in your edited comment, the second column will be exponential-format. Consider using tabs instead of spaces, to align the numbers.*

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to use low level functions, you could also use csvwrite.

```
csvwrite( 'final.txt', p)
```